# TFS 2013 environment variables always empty

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

I've defined custom arguments in my xaml build script and provided values:

[image]

Then In my build I get the following instead of actual TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY. This is the string that writes: "dotCover Report..."

```
String.Format("dotCover Report Path: {0}\{1}", DotCoverReportPath, DotCoverReportFileName)
```

It's not translating to actual BUILDDIRECTORY path. What am I doing wrong? I've hit "refresh" several times and still no go. I wanted to get "C:\temp..." etc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate with this case [TFS How to GetEnvironmentVariable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867042/tfs-how-to-getenvironmentvariable-value). **You can't use $TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY in a custom build process.**

Please refer more detailed info about how to use it from this blog [Using Environment Variables in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1035/environment-variables-visual-studio-2013-tfs)