# TFS How to GetEnvironmentVariable value

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, workflow-activity

In my tfs build I've created an argument to which I pass in **$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)**

[image]
Then in my xaml file I've added a variable called "test1" and added GetEnvirenmentVariable" step where I would like to store value of

> TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY

[image]

I can NOT get the value to come through. Output from my build:
[image]

> It prints $(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY) instead of "C:\temp... etc"

Please help!
thanks

Comment: Is this a continuation of the question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34863549/tfs-2013-environment-variables-always-empty

Comment: They are related. But not really. The problem is that there arent many blogs/info about this at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the last paragraph in [this MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850448.aspx):

> ***Use environment data from a custom build process***
>
> If you need to use an environment variable in your [custom build
>   process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx), you can use the `GetEnvironmentVariable` activity to
>   get the data. You can get data from any of the
>   **WellKnownEnvironmentVariables**.
>
> For example, to get the path to the binaries directory, set the **Name**
>   property of the `GetEnvironmentVariable` activity to
>   `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BinariesDirectory`

---

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create a String variable named: BINARIESDIRECTORY.
2. Add `GetEnvironmentVariable (String)` activity, set **Name** = `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BinariesDirectory`
           and **Result** = BINARIESDIRECTORY
3. Add `CopyDirectory` activity, set **Source** = BINARIESDIRECTORY and
   **Destination** = “\servername\drop”

Comment: What if I want "Result" to be dynamic, that is I want to be able to pass through a variable "BUILDDIRECTORY" other times "SOURCESDIRECTORY", that's why I was hoping I could pass in "$(TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY)" OR "$(SOME OTHER WELL KNOW VARIABLE) into "DotCoverReportPath/VARIABLE, and then have it translated to actual value in my workflow. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In the build process, can't be achieved. After all, environment variables are working in programs or scripts. Please see the updated answer,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34888350/tfs-2013-convert-server-path-to-local-path/34890636#34890636

Comment: Got it. thanks. I ended up using if/else. If "true" then use BUILDDIRECTORY, otherwise use "DEPLOYMENTDIRECTORY" both by using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables

Comment: I get this error - The type ‘InArgument(mtbae:WellKnownEnvironmentVariables)’ of property ‘BINARIESDIRECTORY’ could not be resolved. I tried changing the BINARIESDIRECTORY Variable Type to 'WellKnownEnvironmentVariables' still same issue.