# Using Variables in a TFS Build Template

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, msdeploy

We created a build template that accepts the path of a powerscript filename as an argument. Right now it works if I type in the actual path of the script. I would like to pass $(SourceDir) as part of the path, and then replace it with the actual value during the build.

For example:  **$(SourceDir)**\myapp\scripts\scripttorun.ps

Here are the steps that I have done:

- In the template I have created a variable named **DeploymentScript**
- Then ConvertWorkspaceItem **DeploymentScript** -> **DeploymentScriptFilename**
- Then pass **DeploymentScriptFilename** as an argument to PowerShell

Comment: Hi Nick, are you saying about XAML based build?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly duplicate with this case [TFS How to GetEnvironmentVariable value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867042/tfs-how-to-getenvironmentvariable-value). **You can't use $TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY in a custom build process.**

Refer to the last paragraph in [this MSDN document](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/variables):

> ***Use environment data from a custom build process***
>
> If you need to use an environment variable in your [custom build
>   process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx), you can use the `GetEnvironmentVariable` activity to
>   get the data. You can get data from any of the
>   **WellKnownEnvironmentVariables**.
>
> For example, to get the path to the binaries directory, set the **Name**
>   property of the `GetEnvironmentVariable` activity to
>   `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.BinariesDirectory`

Please refer more detailed info about how to use it from this blog [Using Environment Variables in Visual Studio 2013 and TFS 2013](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1035/environment-variables-visual-studio-2013-tfs)